# What is the relation between a verb and an adverb (officially) called?

Tags: verbs, adverbs

What does an adverb "do" to a verb? When googling I found terms like *modifies* or *describes*, but I'm not sure if a name for the relation exists.

Comment: There is no 'official' grammar; instead there are a variety of competing formalisms or schemes, each with their own terminology. I personally would say an adverb _modifies_ a verb. In dependency grammar the adverb _depends on_ the verb.

Comment: Adverbs don't have to "do" anything to verbs. Adverbs can modify verbs, but more frequently they modify phrases and clauses that contain a predicate (which is often a verb). Then you wouldn't say it modifies the verb, but rather the verb phrase or clause.

Comment: It's perfectly OK to say that prototypical adverbs modify verbs (and other categories other than nouns), e.g. "She almost died".  When we talk of modifiers in clause structure, we often call them adjuncts, though other categories such as PPs can be adjuncts too.